# JSON data is not showing in localhost Chrome Browser

Tags: google-chrome, extjs, sencha-touch

The kitchensink example is working fine in my Chrome browser
http://cdn.sencha.io/touch/sencha-touch-2.1.0/examples/kitchensink/index.html#demo/jsonp

But when I downloaded the code of it and run on local server, it remains in state of data loading.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because of cross-origin errors you get in the javascript...

```
Go to your chrome shortcut -> right click -> properties -> shortcut
```

Change the target field from:

```
"C:\Users\boris.d\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
```

to

```
"C:\Users\boris.d\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files"
```

and it will work for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

add JSONView as extension in your chrome browser and refresh your page.It will work.

use following link to add:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc/related?hl=en

Comment: This extension is useful only if you manage to resolve the cross-origin error issues you get in javascript.